# When deploying Xtext, how to integrate with Eclipse via plugin?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, dsl, xtext

I have finished a beta of my Xtext and Xtend project. Now I want to integrate it with an Eclipse. Using this new Eclipse I want to be able to choose "New 'mydsl' project", then in this new project I want to have a .jar referenced by default. Also an empty file of mydsl. If it is possible, get rid of adding Xtext nature to project .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several non-trivial processes for this question:

1. To be able to choose "New 'yourDSL' project", you will have to implement your own project wizard. That is, in your plugin.xml file you have to contribute to the extension point "**org.eclipse.ui.newWizards**" and create a class that must implement the INewWizard interface, you can do so by extending the Wizard class.
2. That wizard, in the **performFinish**() task, should create a **IJavaProject** programatically where you can specify  the Natures that you want. You also will have to specify the source and output folders, and configure the classpath (adding the classpath entries) as well. This link goes on more detail on how to create the project. http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2008/11/18/extending-eclipse-creating-a-java-project-without-displaying-a-wizard.html
3. In the previous step (#2), when creating your custom project, you can add packages, folders, files, so you can add your empty .mydsl files.
4. Now the trickiest part. To have the .jar file referenced by default there are several approaches. The easiest one is if you know the .jar path beforehand, you can add the reference by adding (in step #2) a classpath entry of type **CPE_LIBRARY** that point to that .jar file, but again you need to know the path somehow. In my case I didn't know the path because my .jar file was a library exported as plugin, so I ended up by implementing an **IClasspathContainer** that looks up for my plugin-library (.jar file) among the installed plugins. You can look up for your a plugin by doing:

`Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("com.my.libraryPlugin");`

`File bundleFile = FileLocator.getBundleFile(bundle);`

... and then, in step #2 what I add is a classpath entry of type **CPE_CONTAINER**:

```
JavaCore.newContainerEntry("MY_CONTAINER");
```

You can read more about **IClasspathContainer** here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-eclipse-classpath/section2.html

5- You probably know how to do this already. The last step is to export your DSL plugins and copy them in the "plugins" folder in the Eclipse installation. To export the plugins: Select the projects -> Right-click -> Export -> Plug-in Development -> Deployable plug-ins and fragments...

Comment: Semih Korkmaz, if it worked, could you please put a step-by-step tutorial here (in your question) or somewhere in internet?